# Как вы работаете с sass в bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, gulp, sass

В доках весь код на scss. 
Сейчас пытаюсь изменить брейкпоинт, но появляется какая то не понятная ошибка(может я туплю).
Код:

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
```

@import '../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss'

Текст ошибки: *app\sass\custom.sass
Error: unclosed parenthesis
on line 1 of app/sass/custom.sass
 $grid-breakpoints: ( {
-------------------^*

Но как вы видите, ни какой скобки там нет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `@import '../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';` вы забыли `;`? из вашего скрина, строчка 9.

Comment: такая ошибка возникает из-за разделителей. Под стрелкой не видно, окончания строк. каждый элемент должен заканчиваться запятой, после последнего элемента запятой быть не должно

Answer (score 3):

> Сейчас пытаюсь изменить брейкпоинт, но появляется какая то не понятная ошибка

`@import '../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';` вы забыли `;`? из вашего скрина, строчка 9.

Так должен выглядеть ваш *custom.scss* (если вы уже выбрали этот вариант):

```
// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

$grid-breakpoints: (
  xs: 0,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px
) !default;

//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Ваш код идет до! Объявляется один раз и не может быть переписана :?
//----------------------------------------------------------------
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; // <--- Пропустили
```

Comment: **Вопрос решил !**  Вот как должен выглядеть код:  
`$grid-breakpoints: ( xs: 0, sm: 576px, md: 768px, lg: 992px, xl: 1900px );
@import '../libs/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';  `

Comment: @АнтонФедоров Кастомные файлы подразумевают, что они будут переписывать дефольтные бутстраповские определения, поэтому и должны быть после бутстраповских определений, а не до, как у вас.

Comment: У меня работает, только так как я написал. Если до подключать нет

Comment: @АнтонФедоров вы правы, исправил.